# Progress Bar in moviepy, for a discord bot

Tags: python, discord, moviepy

I'm trying to implement a discord bot that sends the progress of a video exported via python, Moviepy, and don't know how to do that, I approach it using async def callback but its not Working for me, as the function isn't even called by the logger, due to it being async, so is there any suggestions?

```
message = None

async def progress_bar(bar, percentage):
    print(percentage)
    global message
    await message.edit(content=f'Loading... {bar} ({percentage}/100)')

class MyBarLogger(ProgressBarLogger):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.percentage = 0  # Initialize percentage

    async def bars_callback(self, bar, attr, value, old_value=None):
        # Every time the logger progress is updated, this function is called
        self.percentage = (value / self.bars[bar]['total']) * 100

        def generate_loading_bar(progress, length=20):
            bar_length = int(length * progress)
            return '[' + '=' * bar_length + '-' * (length - bar_length) + ']'

        total_iterations = 100  # Adjust the total number of iterations as needed
        progress = self.percentage / total_iterations

        bar = generate_loading_bar(progress)

        await progress_bar(bar, self.percentage)

async def run_loading_bar(final_clip, output_path):
    logger = MyBarLogger()

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        await loop.run_in_executor(executor, lambda: final_clip.write_videofile(output_path, threads=8, codec='libx264', audio_codec='aac', logger=logger))

    final_clip.close()

@bot.tree.command(name="generate",
                  description="",
                  guild=discord.Object(id=GUILD_ID))
async def generate_motivational_video_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    global message

    message = await interaction.response.send_message('Loading...')
    final_clip = VideoFileClip(r'video_path.mp4')
    await run_loading_bar(final_clip, 'test.mp4')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new event loop for the context of the Logger and nest_asyncio. For me the following works:

```
nest_asyncio.apply()

async def test():
    await aio.sleep(0.1)
    logging.info("test")

class MyLogger(ProgressBarLogger):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.loop = aio.new_event_loop()
    
    def bars_callback(self, bar, attr, value, old_value=None):
        self.loop.run_until_complete(test())
```

Hope it helps!